# How to create own Open ID connect authorization server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, openconnect

I created an application for achieving all OAUTH2 grant types such as (Password grant. Client Credentials and Authorization type grant flow). But, now i want to switch authorization type grant flow into open id connect.

Googled the scenario, but all of them are using third party library to generate open id connect token like **(keycloak, google, okta, athelete)**.

How to create a own authorization server in open id connect? It will be helpful if any inputs or link on this case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID (OIDC) is just a layer on top of OAuth 2.0 for Identity at its simplest form. If you do not want to use a library, then you must read the specifications and write the code yourself.

[OpenID Specifications](https://openid.net/developers/specs/)

Study these two Python libraries to see how they did it:

- https://github.com/rohe/pyoidc
- https://github.com/openid/JWTConnect-Python-OidcRP

Answer (score 0):

Why not operate in a more real world manner and out source the security from your app?

Put your efforts into writing a portable standards compliant app that interfaces with a cloud authorization server.

I point my developers to the following type of setup: https://authguidance.com/2019/09/15/developer-domain-setup/